# producing high quality VR for youtube

Tags: youtube, vr

I am trying to generate a high quality VR video to upload to youtube and watch with an Oculus Go. The issue I have is that no matter the quality of the upload the output on youtube seems very compressed and unwatchable. [This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k4fwLSvozNc) is a link to the video.

Workflow to get this point is:

1. Export video from RiScan Pro as a `.avi` (proprietary software for registering laser scan data). I did this at the [suggested resolution for youtube](https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/6178631?hl=en-GB) of 7168 x 3584 and 24 fps.
2. Using ffmpeg stitch `.avi`'s together to create a `.mp4`. I did this in a way as not to lose quality (file size >10 gb). `.mp4` is required in the next step.
3. Inject spatial metadata using the [360 Video Metadata app](https://github.com/google/spatial-media/releases/tag/v2.1) so as to create 360 video.
4. Upload to youtube

Other VR videos available on youtube are incredible quality and I can watch them on my Go e.g. I don't think it's a bandwidth issue.